# Highlight Multiple Dates in WinRT XAML Toolkit - Calendar Control

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 (XAML) App**. I used **WinRT XAML Toolkit - Calendar Control** in it. I want to show **holidays highlighted** on this calendar. Data of holidays comes from **server**(JSON):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ServerResponse.Holidays.Count; i++)
{
    string[] DateArray = ServerResponse.Holidays[i].ActivityDate.Split('-');    
    //Highlight Holidays in calendar
    ActivityCalender.SelectedDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(DateArray[2]), int.Parse(DateArray[1]), int.Parse(DateArray[0]));

}
```

**XAML:**

```
<WinRT:Calendar x:Name="ActivityCalender" 
    SelectedDatesChanged="ActivityCalender_SelectedDatesChanged">            

</WinRT:Calendar>
```

**C#:**

```
private void ActivityCalender_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

The problem is that if one item is added to SelectedDate, previous one gets removed. I checked ***SelectionChangedEventArgs e***. There is 1 **AddedItems** and 1 **RemovedItems**. Why is previous date getting removed if I add another date?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ActivityCalender_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < GetActivityResponseObject.Workouts.Count; i++)
    {
        string[] DateArray = GetActivityResponseObject.Workouts[i].ActivityDate.Split('-');

        ActivityCalender.SelectedDates.Add(new DateTime(int.Parse(DateArray[2]), int.Parse(DateArray[1]), int.Parse(DateArray[0])));
    }
}
```